# Problem with differential equation,someone to give hint?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I tried to switch all without $y'$ on the right side, but I don't get anything.

Does someone have a hint to do this equation $\left(y-x^2\right)y'-x=0 $?

Answer (score 2):

HINT

I would say - substitution $\displaystyle y' = \frac{1}{x'}$ --> Bernoulli's equation for x = x(y).

Edit - completed:

$\displaystyle \left(y-x^2\right)y'-x=0, \quad y' = 1/x'\quad \Rightarrow \quad \frac{y-x^2}{x'}=x\quad \Rightarrow \quad x'+x = y \cdot x^{-1}$

Solution: $\displaystyle x = \pm  \frac{\sqrt{c_1 e^{-2 y}+2 y-1}}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: Are you sure that is the right way to do that ?

Comment: I am sure that is the possible way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems useful to try $y$ as a function of $x^2$, i.e. use the substitution
\begin{equation}
 y(x) = \eta(x^2),
\end{equation}
which means that
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\text{d} y}{\text{d} x} = 2 x \,\eta'(x^2).
\end{equation}
Using this, the differential equation can be written in terms of $\eta$ as
\begin{equation}
(\eta(x^2) - x^2) \eta'(x^2) = \frac{1}{2}.
\end{equation}
Denoting $z = x^2$, we get
\begin{equation}
 (\eta(z) - z) \frac{\text{d} \eta}{\text{d} z} = \frac{1}{2}.
\end{equation}
I'm sure you can take it from here.

PS. Be sure to check out the [Lambert *W* function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).